# Why am I getting "Matches multiple schemas when only one must validate." when trying to define multiple debug/launch configurations in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, json, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code as my IDE and need multiple debuggers available for the various projects.  I have Extendscript as one and would like to have Chrome for other files.

This is my launch.json file:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "type": "extendscript-debug",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Ask for script name",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${command:AskForScriptName}",
            "stopOnEntry": false
        }
    ]
}
```

VSC is complaining about it "Matches multiple schemas when only one must validate." having two schema.
Also VSC is providing this:  "Configuration 'Launch Chrome against localhost' is missing in 'launch.json'."

I'm able to debug the Extendscript files (jsx) but not the JS or HTML/JS/CSS files.

I am totally lost as used to use ESDK for jsx files and did Chrome in the browser.  There seems to be no way to select the debugger I need.

I'm on Win10 very latest 1909 and VSC Version: 1.44.2 (user setup)

```
Commit: ff915844119ce9485abfe8aa9076ec76b5300ddd
Date: 2020-04-16T16:36:23.138Z
Electron: 7.1.11
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363
```

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the complaining message, this might be a mismatch. Please restart the VS Code first. The messages should disappear after restart.

For setup of multiple debuggers, you need to add configuration separately to `launch.json`, like what you have done in your current `launch.json`, and you can choose the debugger you want to run in the option.

Try the following steps to get the Chrome debugger working:

1. Go to Extensions View (⇧⌘X) and search for `Debugger for Chrome` extension and then install.
2. You have specified `http://localhost:8080` in your chrome url of the configuration, so you have to run a web server on that URL. Like step 1, go to Extensions View to search for `Live Server` extension and then install. Moreover, go to Command Palette (⇧⌘P) with **Preferences: Open Settings (JSON**), add the below snippet:

```
{
    "liveServer.settings.port": 8080,
}
```

This will set custom port number of Live Server. In your case, 8080.

3. Click `Go Live` at the bottom right of VS Code to start the server. This will open a new Chrome browser. You can close it or leave it there.
4. Go to Run View (⇧⌘D) and select `Launch Chrome` option to run the debugger. It will launch a new Chrome browser, and at this point you should be able to start debugging by setting breakpoints.

You can see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/debugging for more useful information and https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug#using-the-debugger for Debugger for Chrome in specific.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27909939)

Comment: @LogicalBranch thank you for the feedback. I have updated my answer with detailed information. Hope it meets your expectation this time.

Comment: "Regarding the complaining message, this might be a mismatch. Please restart the VS Code first. The messages should disappear after restart." -- I had the same message ("Matches multiple schemas when only one must validate.") and reloading VS Code indeed fixed it. Weird, but helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Glad it helped resolve the issue. This was my first time answer a question on Stack Overflow. An upvote would be really appreciated.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just restart VSCODE